# ¿Cómo validar un XML que recibo en un Web-service .asmx con un xsd?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice

Tengo un Web-service en `.asmx` que recibe unos elementos (parámetros o atributos) de un *XML*. Este *XML* a veces lo recibo sin algún elemento.

¿Cómo puede devolver mi Web-service un aviso de error que falta X elemento a la petición?

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer validándolo con el *XSD*?

Comment: qué has intentado?

Comment: No se como tengo que validarlo con el xsd que tengo en mi webservice

Comment: es más fácil ayudarte si nos muestras el código que llevas hasta ahora, puedes poner un comentario en donde debería ir el código que no sabes como hacer :D

Comment: podrias poner como es la firma del metodo que expone el web service ? o sea si recibe los valores como string o si es una clase

Comment: Ok, mirare a ver como puedo  añadir un ejemplo de codigo

Comment: Sin conocer los parametros como puede conocer si el xml es la serializacion que mapea contra una clase, puede que la validaicon del xml tenga que realizarla el cliente y no el servidor ya que si se invoca con un xml incorrecto simplemente no recibe el dato en la propiedad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas .NET 3.5 o superior, puedes validarlo de manera simple utilizando `XDocument` y `XmlSchemaSet`.

Mira este ejemplo para la consola:

```
schemaFileName = @"C:\la\ruta\de\mi.xsd";
filename = @"C:\la\ruta\de\el.xml";
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(schemaNamespace, schemaFileName);

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
string msg = "";
doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) => {
    msg += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;
});
Console.WriteLine(msg == "" ? "El documento XML es válido" : "Documento XML inválido: " + msg);
```

Más información en la [documentación del MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb340331.aspx).

Con información de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11801566/255257) de StackOverflow en inglés.

Comment: Voy a probarlo, alomejor me sirve el código que me mandastes

Comment: pero es un web service, no recibe el xml desde un archivo. Ademas sin conocer los parametros como sabes que el xml no es la serializacion que mapea contra una clase, puede que la validaicon del xml tenga que realizarla el cliente y no el servidor ya que si se invoca con un xml incorrecto simplemente no recibe el dato en la propiedad

Comment: Ahora no puedo probarlo, voy a ver si mañana me sale

Comment: @LeandroTuttini lo que comentas que lo valide el cliente antes de enviar podría ser otra opción. Pero me interesa que el webservice me devuelva almenos un error que diga que los parámetros de XML que recibo le falta algún elemento o esta mal construido.

Comment: @Leandro, la redacción del AP me deja claro que la validación se está llevando a cabo en el servidor y que lo que se recibe es directamente el XML. Sé que al ser un WebService el XML no va a estar en un archivo, pero consideré que el AP estaría en capacidad de adaptar el ejemplo que le dejo, y que el ejemplo es más útil escrito de esa forma, para la comunidad en general.